# How many arguments can I pass to a bash function?

Tags: bash

Is the number of arguments that a bash function can accept limited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html.gz#Arrays) says:

> There is no maximum limit on the size
>   of an array, nor any requirement that
>   members be indexed or assigned
>   contiguously.

I believe this applies, since function arguments are presented as an array.

Answer (score 20):

To access arguments in a function, you can iterate over them:

```
foo () {
    for arg    # "in $@" is implied
    do
        echo $arg
    done
}
```

or

```
bar () {
    while [ $1 ]
    do
        echo $1
        shift
    done
}
```

or to access specific arguments:

```
baz () {
    # for arguments above $9 you have to use curly braces
    echo $1 $9 ${10} ${121375}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The number is fairly large:

```
$ display_last_arg() { echo "${@: -1}"; }
$ getconf ARG_MAX
262144
$ display_last_arg {1..262145}
262145
$ echo $(( 2**18 )) $(( 2**20 ))
262144 1048576
$ display_last_arg {1..1048576}
1048576
```

As you can see, it's larger than [the kernel ARG_MAX limit](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/arg-max.html), which makes sense since Bash does not call `execve(2)` to invoke Bash-defined functions.

I get `malloc` failures if I try to perform Bash sequence expansion (`{1..NUM}`) in the 2^32 range, so there is a hard limit somewhere (might vary on your machine), but Bash is so slow once you get above 2^20 arguments, that you will hit a performance limit well before you hit a hard limit.